# How do you align objects along a vertex using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes, trying to align my trees along a plane with beveled edge, however they are not standing perpendicular to the plane (or directly vertical as I want them), instead they laying parallel to the plane with a seeming random rotation along the x and y axes despite having no modifier changing the rotation of the trees.[image: Beveled plane with trees laying flat.]

Node tree configuration.[image: Node tree]

Thanks

Comment: But how do you really do anything "along a vertex"?.. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your tree has a rotation. Check this: Select tree and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → Apply Rotation

Comment: Yep that did it - Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct